When is $a^x + b^x \equiv a + b \pmod{n}$?
I came across the following result earlier: $$(4^7 + 2^7) = 0 \pmod 6$$ Which I've seen occur in other forms before, leading me to speculate that there exist numbers n and x such that $$a^x + b^x \equiv a + b \pmod{n}$$ However, I do not know how to prove this, let alone figure out which numbers satisfy this property. Thoughts?

If $n$ is prime and neither $a$ nor $b$ are divisible by $n$, then $a^{n} + b^{n} \equiv a + b \bmod n$. Then the congruence holds for all $a$ and $b$ (by FLT). If $n$ can be factored into $n = p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_m^{k_m}$ where each $p_i$ is prime, then it suffices to consider the congruence modulo each of these prime powers. The given congruence holds if it holds for each $p_i^{k_i}$ by the CRT. I suspect you could break it into more cases depending on $n$. There may even be a general answer, I do not know.

@codeing_monkey If $n$ is prime then the result holds for all $a$ and $b$ with $x=n$, by Fermat's Little Theorem.

@ArturoMagidin Oops, thanks.

Euler's theorem says that for $a,n$ coprime, $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, where $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's totient function, the number of numbers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$. Using this, for any $a,b$ coprime to $n$, your equation holds for $x=\varphi(n)+1$

@CameronBuie What is true, as has been mentioned, is that if $x\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(n)}$ and $\gcd(n,ab)=1$, then it holds.

@ArturoMagidin Thank you for setting me straight. I should know better than to trust my symbolic memory alone, at this point.

$k^7\equiv k\pmod{6}$ for all integers $k,,$ by $n=6$ in the linked dupe. $\ \ $

This is a comment not an answer. I saw the following problem in the book Number theory by Sierpinski:

Find smallest composite solutions for $n$ such that $n|2^n-2$ and $n|3^n-3$.

The solution is $n=561=3\times 11\times 17$ so that $ 2^{561}\equiv 2\bmod 561$ and $3^{561}\equiv 3 \bmod{561}$ which results in
$$2^{561}+3^{561}\equiv 2+3\bmod 561$$
Another solution is $n=1105=5\times 13\times 17$ so $$2^{1105}+3^{1105}\equiv 2+3\bmod 1105$$
For $a=2$ and $b=3$, there may be many $n$ to satisfy $a^n+b^n\equiv a+b\bmod n$. It can be shown that for every natural number  $a$ there are infinitely many even numbers  $n$ such that $n|a^n-a$. Suppose we also have numbers $b$ and $m$ such that $m|b^m-b$ and also $(m, n) = p_1p_2 \cdots$, then we have:
$$a^{p_1p_2\cdots}+b^{p_1p_2\cdots}\equiv a+b\bmod p_1 p_2\cdots$$
Update: From the same book:
It can be shown that for any natural number $a>1$, there are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $n|a^n+1$.
Suppose for another natural number $b$ we also have $n|b^n+1$, then we may write:
$$a^n\equiv -1 \bmod n\Rightarrow a^{n+1}\equiv -a \bmod n$$
$$b^n\equiv -1 \bmod n\Rightarrow b^{n+1}\equiv -b \bmod n$$
Which gives:
$$a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}\equiv-(a+b)\bmod n$$
If this is true then we can conclude that:
$$a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}\equiv|(a+b)|\bmod n$$
Here $x=n+1$.

how is this a particular case? And why are you writing comma instead of product?

@Jakobian, because a and are particular numbers 2 and 3.

I've tried editing your answer to make it more comprehensible, but its still unclear. What does "like $a$", "like $b$", "like $n$" mean?

$561$ and $1105$ are Carmichael nimbers, which explains much. Do you know of any non-Carmichael solutions?

@OscarLanzi, I do not think there is any non-carm...numbers for this question.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
